# Showing error "Don't have permission to access the archive" when trying to access the Google Cloud Functions archive

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

A GCP Cloud function which was created by previous collegue. When I am trying to access the same getting permission error as shown in the attached screen shot.

Can anyone guide to narrow down the problem?

[Error accessing GCP Functions archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3azZ.jpg)

I have done the following but still the error stays.

1. Attached the project to proper billing account.
2. Provided access to the actual email which is used to create the Cloud Function. In this case the GCP login Id and created user are same.

Comment: Have you the rights to access to storage bucket? Go to Cloud Storage and reach the file on the bucket

Comment: I checked the storage bucket but there are no objects in it.
I also came to know that these cloud functions are uploaded using firebase. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Sorry maybe I don't fully understand the problem... Do you have the source code of the function? If so, probably the easiest way is to redeploy it. If you don't have the source code but you can login with an account that has access to the remote function then you can download it (from firebase or gcp bucket... where it is)